BEst flooring interface
New build, kitchen floor is LVT, adjacent to prefinished hardwood hallway. What is the best way to interface the two materials, so that the surface is continuous, i.e., no thresholds, no discontinuities, etc. for ease of wheelchair passage? Possible ideas are grout, flexible caulk, or ???

Are the 2 floors already close to the same level? Or is there a difference in height due to the thickness of the materials ie: LVT 3/16" thick and hardwood floor 5/8" thick, setting on the same subfloor level? Last thing is the LVT glued down or floating?

There are a number of transitions made for this.  Is there a great difference in height that would prevent use of a transition?

@Jack  The two floors are exactly the same level. LVT is glued down.

Then a picture of the joint in question would be most beneficial. If the floor guys had their act together, since it is glued down they could have ran the LVT pretty tight to the wood floor, leaving only about a 1/16", which is negligible, a line of clear caulk would have sealed it from getting traffic dirt in it,

@Jack  Not built yet so no pix.

Then it's an easy one then. The floor installers will only need to run the floor to within the 1/16" and caulk the joint. If the floor is glued down properly it will not lift, and presumably the wood floor will stay put too. After that, its controlling contaminants into the glue layer of the LVP, which really shouldn't occur anyway, caulk is mainly for housekeeping. If it was a floating floor it would be a whole different matter.
